# Posting BASE64 image and message via js API message is not UTF-8 encoded

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, character-encoding, base64

We are posting a BASE64 image to a user album together with a status message.
Everything works fine but if the status message contains non base ASCII characters those are not correctly encoded.

We tried:

```
var encodedPng = imageData.substring(imageData.indexOf(',')+1,imageData.length);
    imageData = Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng);

    // this is the multipart/form-data boundary we'll use
    var boundary = '----ThisIsTheBoundary1234567890';
    // let's encode our image file, which is contained in the var
    var formData = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
    formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="' + filename + '"\r\n';
    formData += 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n';

    for ( var i = 0; i < imageData.length; ++i )
        formData += String.fromCharCode( imageData[ i ] & 0xff );

    formData += '\r\n';
    formData += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
    formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data;  name="message"\r\n';
    formData += 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n';
    formData += message + "\r\n"
    formData += '--' + boundary + '--\r\n';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open( 'POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+picMood.fb_album_id+'/photos?access_token=' + token, true );

    xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
        if(typeof callback == "function")
            callback();
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type",    "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + boundary);
    xhr.sendAsBinary( formData );
```

If we samply post the status message via FB.api(...) character are indeed encoded correctly.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

> We are posting a BASE64 image to a user album together with a status message

No, you're posting the decoded *binary* data. Don't do that. Get rid of this line:

```
imageData = Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng);
```

and instead upload `encodedPng` *as base64 data*. Assuming the API is designed to handle base64 data, it should be fine. If it's not, and you really *do* need to upload the binary data, you shouldn't try to do that using form-encoded text.